# getter setter for Hashmap using generics

Tags: java, generics

I have the following two classes

Animal Class

```
class Animal {

  Map<String, A> data = new HashMap <String, A>();

  public void setValue(HashMap<String, ?> val)
   {
     this.data = val;
   }
  public Map getValue()
   {
    return this.data;
   }
}
```

Dog Class

```
class Dog extends Animal {

  public void index()
  { 
    Map<String, A> map = new HashMap<String, A>();

    map.put("name", "Tommy");
    map.put("favfood", "milk"); // want to pass Lists, Integers also
    setValue(map);
  }
}
```

As you can see from the above code I am trying to set some values with keys in `index` method, but I am getting error warnings from eclipse in both two files. Error Messages are:

In Dog Class File:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - A cannot be resolved 
     to a type
    - A cannot be resolved 
     to a type
```

In Animal Class File :

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - A cannot be resolved to a type
    - A cannot be resolved to a type
    - Incorrect number of arguments for type Map<K,V>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments 
     <HashMap<String,A>>
```

The data type of the keys in HashMap will always be a String but the data types of values would be random, hence I am trying to use Generics.

Coming from PHP background I still haven't been able to grasp the concept of Java Generics. Could you please tell me where is the mistake in my code?

Comment: Try to avoid the mix of Generic and RAW type.

Comment: What is A supposed to be?

Comment: Use `Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>()` to store any type of value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this kind of setup is not the ideal way to go, one solution is to make your Map a `<String, Object>` generic type. In this way you can put whatever you want into the Object part. This will, however, be a pain to pull that information back out. This is how I see your classes changing.

```
class Animal {

      Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap <String, Object>();

      public void setValue(Map<String, Object> map)
       {
         this.data = map;
       }
      public Map<String, Object> getValue()
       {
        return this.data;
       }
    }

class Dog extends Animal {

      public void index()
      { 
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        map.put("name", "Tommy");
        map.put("favfood", "milk"); // want to pass Lists, Integers also
        setValue(map);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should *not* be using a `Map` for this; this is not like PHP.

Instead you should be creating a class that knows the type of each of its fields:

```
class Animal {
  String name;
  String favfood;
  int someIntegerField;
  List<Foo> someListField;
  ...
}
```

You should really only be using a `Map` when all the keys and all the values have the same type.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.The keys are not fixed, so I cannot create a class like above.

Comment: Why aren't the keys fixed?  How is your application supposed to work, if you don't know what fields are present and with what types?

Answer (score 0):

```
A cannot be resolved to a type
```

It just means that you are using class "A" which does not exist. For example here `Map<String, A> data` you are saying, that you are creating Map, where string is key and the value is type "A".

In comparision, this `Map<String, Integer>` would mean, that you create map, which has string as key and integer as associated value to its key.

Comment: @black_belt - well its all wrong, there is nothing like "fix this and it will rok" :). Just read and try some tutorials on web, then come back if something does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Map<String, A>` has the undefined type `A` in its declaration.
The problem is, that `A` is never specified and therefore can not be used as a Type for anyting.

The solution would be to either use the *wildcard type* or use `Object` instead of `A`.

Here are the two example solutions:
    `Map<String, ?> data = new HashMap <String, ?>();`
or
    `Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap <String, Object>();`

The same thing has to be applied to the map in your `Dog` class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't just introduce a type parameter in Java generics and expect it to work. For example looking at the `Animal` class:

```
class Animal {

  Map<String, A> data = new HashMap <String, A>();

  public void setValue(HashMap<String, ?> val)
   {
     this.data = val;
   }
  public Map getValue()
   {
    return this.data;
   }
}
```

Type parameter `A` is not defined, so in this case, the compiler will look for a class name `A`. You can solve that by introducing a type parameter for the class:

```
class Animal<A> { // <--- <A> introduces A as a type parameter

  Map<String, A> data = new HashMap <String, A>();

  public void setValue(HashMap<String, ?> val)
   {
     this.data = val;
   }
  public Map getValue()
   {
    return this.data;
   }
}
```

However the problem with this is, that you then need to define `A` when you initialise a new `Animal` for example:

```
Animal<String> dog = new Animal<>();
dog.setValue("name", "max");  //<---- ok
dog.setValue("age", 13);      //<---- won't compile
```

What this means however, is that your `data` Map can only map from `String` to `String`, you will not be able to store integers.

You could get around this by using wildcards, like this for example:

```
class Animal {

  Map<String, ?> data = new HashMap <String, A>(); 

  public void setValue(HashMap<String, ?> val)
   {
     this.data = val;
   }
  public Map getValue()
   {
    return this.data;
   }
}
```

Now you can store every data type derived from `Object` in your map, a `String` or even an `Integer`.

```
Animal dog = new Animal();
dog.setValue("name", "max");  //<---- ok
dog.setValue("age", 13);      //<---- ok
```

The problem with this solution is that you are only to retrieve the elements in this map in a type save manner.

```
dog.getValue().get("name")  //<---- ok 
Object name = dog.getValue().get("name")  //<---- ok
```

-- but --

```
String name = dog.getValue().get("name")  //<---- won't compile
```

As by this stage, the type information has been lost and you are left with a map that maps `String` to `Object`

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. I have got the solution. Thanks to Chris Franklin. I prefered his solution because I needed to set my value at once like this `setValue(map);` Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you shouldn't use the mix of Generic type and RAW type same . a easiest way as my opinion is use `Object` instead `A` :

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap <String, Object>();
```